# How can i run call the process function of this C# bandpass filter?

Tags: c#, function, filter

[This filter](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/DSP/BiQuad.cs) has these two functions:

```
public BandpassFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency) //line 248

public float Process(float input) //line 155
```

---

So i have written a test script thusly:

```
sin = new float[44100];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 44100; ++i)
    {
        sin[i] = Mathf.Sin(i/100);
    }

    BiQuad1.BandpassFilter(44100, 440); 

    for (  i = 0; i < 44100; ++i)
    {
        sin[i] = BiQuad1.Process(sin[i] );
    }
```

It all runs fine until i try to use the BiQuad1.Process function, it says one error:

*Process is not a member of BiQuad1,*

and at end of loop another error warning:

*Assets/BiQuad1.cs(17,1): error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other namespace elements except extern alias declarations*

perhaps i have to also use the GaindB and BiQuad void functions?

Comment: Your using clause is most probably placed AFTER your namespace declaration. Place it at the top of your file

Comment: Looking at the source, shouldn't that be `var filter = new BiQuad1.BandpassFilter(44100, 440);`, then `sin[i] = filter.Process(sin[i]);`?

Comment: Not sure what BiQuad1 is either... it does not appear as a class or namespace in the referenced .cs file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to call an instance method as a static class method.  You need to create an instance of a filter and invoke its process method as follows:

```
    sin = new float[44100];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 44100; ++i)
    {
        sin[i] = Mathf.Sin(i/100);
    }

    var bandpass = new BandpassFilter(44100, 440); 

    for (  i = 0; i < 44100; ++i)
    {
        sin[i] = bandpass.Process(sin[i] );
    }
```